# Wix: How to show the size of MSI packages in a burn managed UX

Tags: wix, wix3.6, burn

I have a Wix 3.6 managed bootstrapper in which the user can select individual packages to download and install.  I want to show the download size of each package.  How can I access the file size of each packages in the `Bundle`?

I guess this information is available somewhere in the Wix framework (because the file hashes are used to validate the downloaded files), but I did not find it.

I have an idea for a workaround, but it would be more implementation for me:

- Have a `wxs` file generated programmatically that contains `Variable` elements containing the file size of the packages.  Those variables would be read by the bootstrapper.

Answer (score 1):

When your bundle is created, a `BootstrapperApplicationData.xml` is added to the bundle. That XML file contains a lot of metadata about the bundle and contained packages. Your bootstrapper application code can load this file by looking in the same direcotry as your bootstrapper application dll lives.

Comment: I suppose this is outdated information. I haven't been able to find said file.

Comment: Not outdated information, just memory mistake. Correct name of the file is: `BootstrapperApplicationData.xml` (not `BundleApplicationData.xml`). I fixed the answer after refreshing my memory by looking at the code.

Answer (score 0):

I did not found how by using the burn API, but I implemented my own workaround:

```
If the local file is present
   query the file system
else
   query the web server
```